# minkube external-ip always in pending state while not able to access emissary-ingress loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, ambassador

I am sure because of my little knowledge on kubernetes as well as on minkube, I am not able to resolved and I require some help.

I have setup minikub kubernetes cluster on windows-docker. (latest version). I am trying to setup emissary-ingress API Gateway which forwards the traffic based on URL Prefix (like /hello/ send the traffic to hello kubernetes service) I have setup all those ingress traffic rules but unfortunately, I stuck on How to test that.

I am not able to access the URL. here is my configuration.
I tried understanding following way.

```
kubectl get svc -A
```

[image]

```
minikube service list
```

[image]

```
minikube tunnel
```

[image]

```
minikube service emissary-ingress -n emissary --url
```

[image]

[image]

But I did not understood why is that not working. I am sure something to do with external-ip pending status. but I am not sure How to resolved it.

[image]

Comment: below answer satisfying your issues? could you please update status of question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [metalLb](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

Metal LB is creating the load balancer on bare metal and can be used locally with minikube.

With metal lb you can create the external LB same way like Cloud provider gives the option.

Try applying this file : `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.7.3/manifests/metallb.yaml`

Check pod are up & running or not

```
kubectl get pods -n metallb-system
```

Configure the configmap for local system so metal lb can manage the IP.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: my-ip-space
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 127.0.0.240/28
```

You can read more here : https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/kubernetes-metal-lb-for-docker-for-mac-windows-in-10-minutes-23e22f54d1c8 baki kai vandho ave to kevu

or else you can also try **Port-forwarding** the service of **API gateway** and check that out working or not.

Comment: That link to install metallb is outdated. Please use the official doc to install it: https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Use minikube tunnel:

`minikube tunnel`

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access

A LoadBalancer service is the standard way to expose a service to the internet. With this method, each service gets its own IP address.

Services of type LoadBalancer can be exposed via the minikube tunnel command.

When you start minikube tunnel you will see how an external ip is added to the service.